# Changing tone during a sentence and having "and/or" in a list

Tags: punctuation, diction

I am unsure about the following sentence:

> "Reasons a guest may be turned away include, but are not limited to, **being** under the influence of drugs or alcohol, **exceeding** the weight limit, **unable** to understand or obey the rules, **and are** physically unable to traverse the obstacles."

When running through this sentence, I can't help but feel a few things are off. As it reads, it seems the tone of the sentence has changed. By that I mean the words "**being**" and "**unable**" don't seem to fit well. Thoughts?

Aside from that, I am not sure whether to use "*and/or*" instead of "*and*"; nor of the impact that "*and/or*" might have on a sentence when used in the middle of a list. Would this change the necessary punctuation?

Comment: "And/or" is nowhere to be seen. The problem is merely one of grammatical parallelism. If you start your first list item with an *-ing* form of a verb, stick with that choice for the rest of the items too. Your *being* and *exceeding* are parallel OK, but *unable* should become *being unable* both times. Actually, though, *inability* would also work both places, since the *-ing* forms in question are gerunds, which are a type of nominalization, and *inability* is the more usual and economical nominalization of *unable.*

Comment: @BrianDonovan OP means should "and/or" be used instead of "and".  I've edited the Q. accordingly.

Comment: "......inability to understand....and physical inability to..."

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence reads as follows and includes four separate reasons:

> Reasons a guest may be turned away include ...
>    - being under the influence of drugs or alcohol,
>    - exceeding the weight limit,
>    - unable to understand or obey the rules, and
>    - are physically unable to traverse the obstacles.

I have broken it up like that to show you that the wording of the four individual clauses (reasons) all need to be able to follow directly from your first line *"Reasons ... include"*.

So which of the following are acceptable:

> 1. Reasons ... include ... being under the influence of drugs or alcohol;
> 2. Reasons ... include ... exceeding the weight limit;
> 3. Reasons ... include ... unable to understand or obey the rules, and
> 4. Reasons ... include ... are physically unable to traverse the obstacles.

Nos. 1 & 2 read acceptably.
No. 3 needs to read "***being*** unable to understand ...
No. 4 needs to read "***being*** physically unable ...

So I would rephrase your sentence as:

> Reasons a guest may be turned away include, but are not limited to,
>    - being under the influence of drugs or alcohol,
>    - exceeding the weight limit,
>    - *being* unable to understand or obey the rules, and
>    - *being* physically unable to traverse the obstacles.

As regards changing "*and*" to "*and/or*", I would say that that is unnecessary, because it is obvious that:

- merely one reason is enough to be turned away;
- it is a *list* of reasons (so "*and*" is appropriate).

Additionally, your list is specifically stated to be *not* exhaustive ("*but are not limited to ...*") and adding "or" would only cause confusion.